# Get complete/unescaped/unsplit command string in custom CommandProvider

Tags: java, osgi

I wrote a custom [`CommandProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/osgi/framework/console/CommandProvider.html) implementing a command (`cphr`):

```
public void _cphr(CommandInterpreter ci){
/* ... *
}
```

which is supposed to just forward the given query to a [cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html) execution engine. So, an example invocation:

```
osgi>cphr <query>
```

is passed to an engine like so:

```
ExecutionEngine eng = new ExecutionEngine(...);
ExecutionResult er = eng.execute(query);
```

The `CommandProvider`-Interface is optimized for token-based access, so it's implementation splits the `query` into tokens, over which I can iterate `ci.nextArgument()`.

This is *problematic*, as single-quotes, e.g., are stripped and have to be explicitly escaped to be preserved. So, a valid query:

```
cphr start n=node(*) where n.pathTime='2013-11-05-10-36-7' return n
```

results in a syntax error:

```
Invalid input '5': expected '.', whitespace, '[', node labels, "=~", IN, IS, '*', '/', '%', '^', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, START, MATCH, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 44) " start n=node(*) where n.pathTime=2013-11-05-10-36-7 return n"
```

Whereas, the escaped query works:

```
cphr start n=node(*) where n.pathTime=\'2013-11-05-10-36-7\' return n
```

Is there a way to access the command line as the user provided it in a `CommandProvider` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to get all arguments (at once) from a `CommandInterpreter`. But I would nevertheless go another way.

You are providing a query to your command. This query is the one (!) argument to your command. So I would do two things:

1. In the command implementation (here `_cphr`), I would enforce, that there is only one argument.
2. If the argument (the query) contains spaces - which it usually has, then this argument itself must be quoted: `> cphr "start n=node(*) where n.pathTime='2013-11-05-10-36-7' return n"`

Comment: Thx for your suggestions. Especially the second one is quite  obvious...*g*